# How do I add new libraries to GNAT Studio?

Tags: ada

So I have a few AdaCore github libraries I need to clone and include in my project. However; they are not being picked up by GNAT studio -- cannot cross reference or build my project with them  as they are not found. The particular one I'm dealing with at the moment is `aws` but I have a number of others I need to use so would like to spot my error before spending yet more time trying to fix this.

Note I followed the install process on `aws`, and this is on Ubuntu 20.04 using the latest GPL edition of GNAT from the AdaCore site.

So I need to know the correct paths where they should be in my installation.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can check if a library is properly installed with command `gprinstall --list` If `aws` is on the list, then everything is ok, you can go to step 2. If not, please check once more the installation documentation.
2. I don't remember the UI of GNAT Studio, but you can edit your project file (this one which ends with extension `.gpr`, for example: `myproject.gpr`) in a text editor too. At the top of the project file add line `with aws;` (if you want to add `aws` library to your project) so GNAT can find the library. If you want to add another libraries, just add them under `with aws;` in similar manner. You can find their names by using `gprinstall --list` command.